# Salesforce - define custom object via REST API

Tags: rest, salesforce

Is there a method to create my own custom object in Salesforce via the REST API? I can interact with records of custom objects when they're pre-defined in the Salesforce instance. For instance:

A POST request to `https://<instance_A>.my.salesforce.com/services/data/vXX.0/sobjects/_customObject_xxx` will generate a new record of the `_customObject_name` type.

Now, suppose I have another Salesforce instance (instance_B). I want to define the same `_customObject_xxx` in instance_B using the REST API. I came across this documentation: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_custom_objects.htm, but it doesn't mention defining custom objects via the REST API.

Is there any REST alternative to the Metadata API? Do you have any insights?